# import / reuse common strings.xml between different flavours android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

My problem: I have many different flavors of an android app. Now every time I want to add/modify a string in the string.xml file I need to change it in every string.xml file for every flavour.

What I want to achieve is the ability to import common strings therefore having the ability to modify strings in one location and it reflect on all the flavours.
I scoured the internet for solutions. I came across global entitys:

For Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE resources [
<!ENTITY %ents SYSTEM "../raw/entities.ent">
%ents;
]>
....
<string name="app_name">&app_name;</string>
```

The two main problems with this is:

1. I still have to add a string tag for each strings.xml file so it doesn't really solve my problem
2. This solution is deprecated because of XXE attacks

Maybe there is a trivial solution and I'm just missing it?
Is it even possible?

Any advice/references will be much appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: a code generation task during the build process sounds like a reasonable option as well

Comment: a build task that generates all necessary xml files for your flavors, using a common xml as source. Something like maven generate-sources.